# Get List of all users from Openfire Server in Android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

Hello i am developing a chat app in android using xmpp and open-fire for server,

currently i can create new user and login with that user.

i have searched a lot of on net and tried different solutions but nothing is worked.

at server all users are automatically get added to one default group. when new user get created.

but i am unable to get list of all users until i will add them to my roster.

**my requirement is to show all user's list and allow user to add friend from them, how to get all users list those who are not my friend?**

**i have tried to get list of users from group, but still no success, i can only retrieve list of users those are my friends with following code.**

```
Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

            for(RosterEntry entry1 : entries)
            {
                System.out.println("UserID:- " + entry1.getUser());
                System.out.println("Name:- " + entry1.getName());
                System.out.println("Status:- " + entry1.getStatus());
                System.out.println("type:- " + entry1.getType());   
            }
```

**to retrieve user entry from group i used following code**

```
    Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterGroup> groups = roster.getGroups();
    for(RosterGroup group: groups )
            {
                System.out.println("Group Name:- " + group.getName());
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

            for(RosterEntry entry1 : entries)
            {
                System.out.println("UserID:- " + entry1.getUser());
                System.out.println("Name:- " + entry1.getName());
                System.out.println("Status:- " + entry1.getStatus());
                System.out.println("type:- " + entry1.getType());   
            }   
        }
```

any help/solution or suggestion to get all users list is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

following code is working for me :

```
UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(connection);

Form searchForm = usm.getSearchForm("search." + connection.getServiceName());
//Here i am searching for the service name

Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();

UserSearch userSearch = new UserSearch();
answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);

answerForm.setAnswer("search", "*");

ReportedData data = userSearch.sendSearchForm(connection, answerForm, "search." + connection.getServiceName());

if (data.getRows() != null) {
    System.out.println("not null");

    Iterator<ReportedData.Row> it = data.getRows();

    arryAllUsers.clear();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        //System.out.println("row");

        ReportedData.Row row = it.next();

        Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");

        if (iterator.hasNext()) {

            String jid = iterator.next().toString(); //here i get all the user's of the open fire..
            // l.add(value);

        }

        // Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure @Prshant patil?

Comment: yes i have already used in my application and it is working @Devendra Singh

Comment: how can you check if the user is online/offline with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following:

1. setup "shared roster" on the server, take a look at https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1619 - every user will have all server users in the roster.
2. when user mark someone as "friend" - add that user to some group, e.g. "Friends". And display that group as user's roster.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. i will have look at those link and let you know will it works for me or not